# from origin 'xxx' has been blocked by CORS policy:

Tags: javascript, node.js, github, cors, axios

I'm trying the most basic `get` request from the browser and it fails due to CORs issues.

```
axios.get(
  "https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?client_id={ID}"
);
```

Is it just not possible to make this request from the browser? I'm trying to understand how it's possible to click a button and have this link work.

> from origin 'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer is **NO**.

You can't call any endpoint (different origin) without server's permission.

#### ok! I got it. But why? How it works ?

It's called CORS *(Cross-Origin Resource Sharing)*. In one line, it is a browser security . Browser blocks you to prevent such request.

#### Ok! but how browers knows that I don't have the permission or I'm cheating. :D

Well, if you check Network Tab of a browser, browser sends one more request to server (before actual request) with `OPTION` method. In the response of the request, server tells to browers if it's valid request or not.

For more details, Read MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Answer (score -1):

> Ideal Solution

Your server should enable the cross origin requests and not the client. To do this, you can check [this cool link](https://enable-cors.org/server.html) with implementations and configurations for multiple platforms

> Front-end fix to try

```
var config = {
    headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}
};

axios.get(
    "https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?client_id={ID}, config"
);
```

> Quick Temporary fix for development

Add [this chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en) to your chrome browser and turn it on. There won't be any cors issue but it is not a permanent fix.